# Will adding .xcdatamodel/layout to the .gitignore cause problems?

Tags: xcode, git, core-data, gitignore

When using Core Data, Xcode seems to modify the `.xcdatamodel/layout` file every time I view the data model. I don't want to commit that change because I haven't done anything. Is it safe to add that file to the .gitignore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experiment it was safe. However, I recommend just letting git back it up. The overhead is minimal, so why should this bother you?

Comment: The overhead doesn't bother me. It's the frequency that it shows up as being modified in `git status`. Also it can cause conflicts when working with branches.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can exclude it. I even tried deleting it, everything still works. As the name `layout` suggests, it seems to affect just the presentation.